# How to setup docx-templates in NextJS (Browser Pollyfill)

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I want to generate some docx based on template but Instead of generating on Server I wanna do it on  browser side, but I am unable to setup correctly in nextjs 13 (appdir).

Please help me thanks!

I tried everything but getting error when I give cdn link!